# Another string gets appended to the end of a string when fetching stuff from a struct

Tags: c, file, struct

Basically I have to output a file named with a student's ID containing todays date, their name, date of birth and their location, and this stuff is stored in a struct.

Problem is when I try to output the location, it outputs the ID to the end of the date of birth. I don't really see what I've done wrong here. I've attached the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
  char name[50];
  char DOB[10];
  char ID[10];
  char location[30];
} student1;

int main(){
    int day, month, year;
    printf("Enter the current day: ");
    scanf("%d", &day);
    printf("Enter the current month: ");
    scanf("%d", &month);
    printf("Enter the current year: ");
    scanf("%d", &year);

    strcpy(student1.name, "My Name");     /*setting struct data*/
    strcpy(student1.DOB, "01/01/1999");
    strcpy(student1.location, "City");
    strcpy(student1.ID, "0000000000");

    char* a;
    strcpy(a, student1.ID);
    char* ext = ".doc";
    int nameLen = strlen(a) + strlen(ext) + 1;          /* ID to file name*/
    char fileName[nameLen];
    FILE *outFile;

    snprintf(fileName, sizeof(fileName), "%s%s", a, ext );

    outFile = fopen(fileName, "w" );

    fputs("The current date is: ", outFile);        /*current date to file*/
    fprintf(outFile, "%d", day);
    fputs("/", outFile);
    fprintf(outFile, "%d", month);
    fputs("/", outFile);
    fprintf(outFile, "%d", year);

    fputs("\nName: ", outFile);
    fputs(student1.name, outFile);
    fputs("\nDate of birth: ", outFile);
    fputs(student1.DOB, outFile);
    fputs("\nLocation: ", outFile);
    fputs(student1.location, outFile);


    fclose(outFile);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is what the file looks like. It has the student ID as the name, e.g 0000000000.doc, but the file itself looks like this

```
The current date is: 11/1/2022
Name: My Name
Date of birth: 01/01/19990000000000
Location:
```

Any help in getting rid of the ID and getting the location in its proper place would be awesome.

Comment: Does the fact DOB's size is EXACTLY the number of characters in the string give you clue?  What happens if you make that field a bit bigger?  If you don't understand why, look into how C strings identify the *end* of the string.

Comment: `strcpy(student1.ID, "0000000000");` :  `student1.ID` has room for 10 chars, `"0000000000"` takes 11 chars (10 + the null terminator). You may have the same problem for other fields. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your learning material.

Comment: `char DOB[10];` -> `char DOB[11];` place for `null` byte.

Comment: You didn't notice that the Location wasn't printed at all (but @Jabberwocky did).

Comment: @ScottHunter The only thing I noticed is that there is at least one buffer overflow. Strings that get magically appended to other strings is a very common pattern with buffer overflows.

Comment: offtopic rant. I wonder why student's C exercises are so heavy on string handling these days... I, as a C++ / DSP / bit of embedded engineer myself, see the appeal of teaching C, but literally the last thing I want to do in C is handling strings. It's a language that doesn't come with the semantics for that, and 50 years of bugs have shown that the way the standard library tools are simply... not good at allowing people to write correct code.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: As C is an *awful* language for an introduction to programming, why not make it as painful as possible?

Comment: Oh and: `char* a; strcpy(a, student1.ID);` is not going to end well....